# Facebook social graph still fetching old values and not the updated ones

Tags: facebook-graph-api, imgur, social-graph

I made a new blog post on my website and provided an image for `SocialGraph` tag:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://i.imgur.com/someOldImage.jpg" />
```

The image was hosted on `imgur`, and posted it on the web.

After few minutes I decided to change the image and updated it to the new image that was also uploaded on the `imgur`. However as far as the html markup is concerned it does show social graph tag values according to the new image.

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://i.imgur.com/someNewImage.jpg" />
```

But when I go to post on facebook the facebook preview shows the `imgur` error that

```
the image you request doesn’t exists or no longer available
```

Which means that FB is still trying to fetch the old image and not the new one even though I have updated it in the markup?

Why is this so, how can I refresh facebook social graph values for the url? Please explain its an important post and this way its like causing an embarrassment?

Answer (score 0):

Go to https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Enter URL and append fbrefresh=CAN_BE_ANYTHING

Example: http://example.com/?fbrefresh=CAN_BE_ANYTHING